# Shipping labels

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

We have our own thermal printer and would like our Magento store to generate labels ready for printing. We are using the couriers Royal Mail and Parcelforce.

What would be the best way to approach this? Are there any extensions that provide this functionality? We ideally want to integrate directly rather than through a third party like [Shiptheory](https://shiptheory.com/)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 1):

Please check below extensions in details

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/royal-mail-shipping-carrier.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/meanbee-royal-mail-domestic-and-international-shipping.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/royal-mail-labels.html

You can search magento extension here 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/